# Get Image src attribute value for HTML5 canvas element

Tags: html, canvas

I have been searching - am thinking what I want to do is not possible but thought I would check.

I have a few canvasses on an HTML page as follows: (these are IDs below)

- canvasMain - this is going to display
  a large version of an image
- canvasThumbnail1 - this is going to
  display a thumbnail image
- canvasThumbnail2 - same as
  above...etc

I have it working where I paint the canvasMain with the contents of the thumbnail.  The problem is since the canvas is immediate it is copying the pixels as they are over to the canvasMain from canvasThumbnail.  This is resulting in an enlarged pixelated image.

What I want to do is click on one of the canvasThumbnails and be able to grab the Image.src property as a string and then pull that into canvasMain instead of actually copying the pixels over from one canvas to another.  Essentially just grab the address (local or say on Flickr) from where I can pull in the image.  Pulling an image in to a canvas seems to scale it nicely.

From what I have seen I do not think that Image.src value is accessible through the 2d context.  I enumerated through its properties and have only found nested objects or native code returns.

I figured that if I clicked on the canvasThumbnail, and then used (this) to get a reference to that canvas element and then grab the 2dcontext of that canvas I may be able to use a property of that context to get a string that represents the value of the Image.src.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Somehow you painted the image onto `canvasThumbnail1`, presumably from a (high resolution) Image element.

The canvasThumbnail1, or any canvas for that matter, has no memory on things painted on it. So if you paint a large Image onto a tiny canvasThumbnail, the high-resolution data does not exist on that tiny canvas. To get it you must use the original image again, or else you must paint to a larger canvas from the start.

In other words, instead of painting the thumbnail onto the main, you need to repaint Image element (that you used to make the thumbnail) onto the main.

Comment: Yes that is correct.  I created a canvas, then got the context.  I then created an image object with an Image.src that was a high resolution image.  Essentially I want to be able to create a thumbnail and then click on it to display it on a larger canvas.

Comment: So all you have to do is draw from the Image object both times

Comment: Yes-correct.  I created a canvas, then got the context.  I then created an image object with an Image.src that was a high resolution image and painted it to the canvas.  Essentially I want to be able to create a thumbnail and then click on it to display it on a larger canvas.  I hoped that there may have been a property available that would let me just pull the image in from the URI instead of copying the pixels over.  I did some testing with it and saw how nicely the canvas could scale an image of any dimension.  I just wanted to verify that I would have to code for this myself. Thanks.

Comment: I think I see what you are saying - I can pull in all the images at page load and then just trap which thumbnail got clicked to render the corresponding canvas.